# Error: 'NameError: name 'terms_and_conditions' is not defined' when it is

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm just finding my way around python/django.  I'm in the middle of trouble shooting another issue with assistance and in the process of trying various things am now seeing this error in my console:

```
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/vaijoshi/PycharmProjects/adec/src/project/urls.py", line 12, in <module>
    url(r'^termsandconditions/$', terms_and_conditions, name='terms_and_conditions'),
NameError: name 'terms_and_conditions' is not defined
```

I'm a little confused as this information is defined in my views.py (at least that's what I think I'm doing)

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from src.adec.forms import UserForm


def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")


def register_professional(request):
    return render(request, "registerprofessional.html")


def register_user(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = UserForm()

    return render(request, 'registeruser.html', {'form': form})


def terms_and_conditions(request):
    return render(request, "termsandconditions.html")


def how_it_works(request):
    return render(request, "howitworks.html")


def search_results(request):
    return render(request, "searchresults.html")


def profile(request):
    return render(request, "profile.html")
```

URL.py in the project folder (note I was advised to move the above views.py from the projects folder to the src folder for the other issue I'm troubleshooting.  Do they need to be in the same folder?)

```
import...

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/docs/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    url(r'^termsandconditions/$', terms_and_conditions, name='terms_and_conditions'),
    url(r'^how-it-works/$', how_it_works, name='how_it_works'),
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^registerprofessional/$', register_professional, name='register_professional'),
    url(r'^registeruser/$', register_user, name='register_user'),
    url(r'^searchresults/$', search_results, name='search_results'),
    url(r'^profile/$', profile, name='profile'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My tree structure atm:

[image: tree]

Kindly assist

Update based on comments below:

I have now done:

from adec.views import terms_and_conditions

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/docs/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    url(r'^termsandconditions/$', terms_and_conditions, name='terms_and_conditions'),
    url(r'^how-it-works/$', how_it_works, name='how_it_works'),
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^registerprofessional/$', register_professional, name='register_professional'),
    url(r'^registeruser/$', register_user, name='register_user'),
    url(r'^searchresults/$', search_results, name='search_results'),
    url(r'^profile/$', profile, name='profile'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is reverting me back to the original error I was facing:

```
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/vaijoshi/PycharmProjects/adec/src/project/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from adec.views import terms_and_conditions
  File "/Users/vaijoshi/PycharmProjects/adec/src/adec/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.adec.forms import UserForm
ImportError: No module named src.adec.forms
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in `urls.py` and not `views.py`.

Comment: @DimitrisJim I have added the urls.py above also.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the name is imported in the `urls.py`:

```
from adec.views import terms_and_conditions
```

Alternatively, use string instead:

```
url(r'^termsandconditions/$', 'adec.views.terms_and_conditions',
    name='terms_and_conditions'),
```

Comment: I have added the urls.py above also.  Is it here I'd do this?

Comment: apologies, yes.  I have added the "import..." which is just before it. v

Comment: @vtj808, I meant `from adec.views import terms_and_conditions`. Does it work now?

Comment: Hey, @falsetru okay so I have just added the statement (see above).  Although I'll be honest, I'm a little confused, why do we need to specify import terms_and_conditions here buy nottt do this for all of the others in urls.py? Also it is no longer coming up with the error but the original error now persists. I have added that also incase you've seen it before (there's another SO link for this.)

Comment: @vtj808, You don't need to `import` if you're using string style view name.

Comment: After a bit of fiddling around I am now getting ImportError: No module named src.project.models.  I got rid of the Import statement at the top of urls.py as suggested but then it gave me another error `
NameError: name 'url' is not defined`On adding import... back it seems to have 'fixed' this issue though I'm not sure. thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95175/discussion-between-vtj808-and-falsetru).